# Security Around Microsoft Azure AD AD "Application Access"

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have successfully configured qn [Azure AD App Registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?view=graph-rest-1.0), allowing a `client_credentials` based OAuth 2.0 flow to work. This allows a third party application to access Microsoft Graph API. The app has "[Calendar.Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference?view=graph-rest-1.0#calendars-permissions)" permission. Meaning the app can pretty much read any of the calendars (including CEO's).

I now have a conversation with security.  What is out there in the Microsoft world, that I can use to lock down usage of API access via this Application Permission?  Is there ability to do things like:

- Restrict IP ranges the App can be accessed from?
- Restrict users that can access the App?  (However in Client_credentials, there is no user context)
- Log traffic / activity happening via the App?

*The only thing i can think of now is to say the Redirect URL configuration on the app means, no other application can get an access token using the Client_credentials, even if the application id & passkey get compromised*

Any advice on further security controls that can be put in place?

Comment: Redirect URL does not matter in client credentials. It is not used. Token acquisition is one HTTP request that you can do from anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are very few options available currently available to offer these controls at token issuance (in Azure AD) or at API access (in Microsoft Graph). However, you can achieve similar results by carefully managing access to the app's credentials. Here are a couple steps you can take (not exhaustive):

**App credentials: keep them secret, keep them safe**

Use Key Vault. You can configure many of the restrictions you mention for access to data in Key Vault, including IP ranges and which users access. Key Vault also offers auditing of access to secrets. Don't forget to also be careful about which users have management access to the Key Vault (e.g. other users with access to the same Azure subscription).

Use certificates (public/private key pair), rather than client secrets (passwords), to authenticate the app. People tend to manage certificates much more carefully than they manage shared passwords, and developers are much less likely to hard-code the secret into scripts/code.

**Be careful and deliberate about which users can manage the app's credentials**

This is often overlooked. A user (or another app) who can access existing credentials, or add a new authorized credential to an app can act as the app and (mis)use all the permissions the app has been granted. This includes:

- Users (and apps) in the "Company Administrator", "Application Administrator" and "Cloud Application Administrator" directory roles.
- Users who are set as owners of the app registration (*Application* object) and enterprise app (*ServicePrincipal* object) for the app.
- Users (or systems) who have access to the server or service the application resides on (which will have, or have access to, the credentials).

For all of these cases, ensure this is the smallest possible number of users, and they actually have a legitimate need. For users who *do* need access, wherever possible enforce just-in-time, time-limited access (not persistent access), such as with [Azure AD Privileged Identity Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/), for time-bound, just-in-time access for Azure AD directory roles and Azure resources.

Answer (score 2):

Restricting access: You would need to do this in your application. The Client Credential flow doesn't allow for restricting what users as you point out. However there is nothing stopping you from adding user authentication to your application, possibly using a delegated graph auth flow to determine who they are.

IP Ranges: This is not possible currently.

Logging Traffic: This is not possible on the graph side currently, however you could/should log traffic on your applications side.

Redirect urls will not help you because they are not used int eh client credential flow.

In general application only auth (client credential flow) + a broad authorization scope is very powerful, but must be managed correctly.  You don't inadvertently want to build a totally new users/permissions model over the top of the graph :)

Comment: It is also possible to use per-user consent and refresh tokens to do similar background work. It's more restrictive but does require per-user consent + it's more brittle than client credentials.

Comment: @juunas indeed, but i pity the person who has to figure out expiry times in a robust manner!!

Comment: @ChrisJohnson Expiry times isn't really an issue (libraries take care of refreshing). The issue is inactivity (where the refresh token could expire) and, more importantly, the assumption by the service that this is an actual human user who can be interrupted and be prompted (e.g. to satisfy a conditional access policy, to change an expired/compromised password, etc.).

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret yes. refresh token expiry is a black hole. you have no deterministic way to know long they last and therefore can't warn the user proactively to login to refresh them for example. it's awful.

Comment: It's what you have to accept to get tighter access to resources. Both approaches have pros and cons :) A SaaS app I was involved in uses the refresh token approach because the feature isn't critical for the product, and doesn't require the customer org to give us org-wide access to their stuff.

Comment: @juunas oh yes i know :) i would just like an expiry to be sent with the refresh token so that we can build apps that work better for users.

Comment: Yeah, but refresh tokens can be invalidated for other reasons than going stale or expiring. So it wouldn't be a complete solution anyway.

Comment: @juunas fair point. but i would rather deal with those less common situations & get the ability to warn users of expiry in return. i guess its just personal priorities :)